# How can I (programmatically) prevent mount of USB storage devices? I'll prefer an answer involving udev

Tags: c++, linux, events, usb, udev

I've been reading udev's documetation and so far, I've not found nothing can help me.

This is what I intend to do:

1. Any user inserts a flash drive.
2. My application catch the event.
3. My app does some checks.
4. Negative result.
5. The user is not able to see the flash drive.
6. Positive result
7. The user is able to see the flash drive.

PD: I'm ok if users can see the flash drive, all I need is prevent they mount it.

This smell like kernel space job. Isn't it? Maybe something related with "avoiding udev events forwarding" or "avoiding udev events propagation"

Comment: Obviously you can't do so under a normal account as that would obstruct `root`.

Comment: why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Looks like a job for [polkit](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/udisks-polkit-actions.html) IMHO.